# MultiBinding with Multiple output

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, imultivalueconverter

Lets consider an animal `Model` as following:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public int age { set; get; }
}
```

and a collection of `Animal` object as following:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Animal>>> animals;
```

in my `ViewModel` I populate `animals` like:

```
var lions = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
lions.Add(new Animal("myLion 1", 2));
var tigers = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
tigers.Add(new Animal("myTiger 1", 1));
var wild = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Animal>>();
wild.Add("Lion", lions);
wild.Add("Tiger", tigers);


var cats = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
cats.Add(new Animal("myCat 1", 2));
cats.Add(new Animal("myCat 2", 4));
var dogs = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
dogs.Add(new Animal("myDog 1", 1));
var pets = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Animal>>();
pets.Add("cat", cats);
pets.Add("dog", dogs);


animals = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Animal>>>();
animals.Add("wild animals", wild);
animals.Add("pets", pets);
```

In the `View` I define two `ComboBox`es and one `DataGrid` which are described as following:

- The first combobox items are `"wild animals"` and `"pets"`, and the `SelectedItem` of combobox binds to `selectedAnimalType` property of `ViewModel`.
- The second combobox items are bound to first combobox selection; i.e., `"cat"/"dog"` or `"lion"/"tiger"` respectively for `"pet"` or `"wild animals"`. The `SelectedItem` of this combobox is bound to `selectedAnimalCategory` property of `ViewModel`.
- The `DataGrid` displays animals based on the selected values of the two comboboxes.

My `DataGrid` is defined and bound as following:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource animalSelectionConverter}">
            <Binding Path="selectedAnimalType"/>
            <Binding Path="selectedAnimalCategory"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Animal Type" Binding="{Binding Path=XYZ}"/> <!--The Question-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding age}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And finally, I define the `AnimalSelectionConverter` as following:

```
public class AnimalSelectionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ViewModel.Default.animals[(string)values[0]][(string)values[1]];
    }    
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Question :**

I'm binding `Animal.name` and `Animal.age` of selected collection of animals to columns of `DataGrid`. However, I'm also interested to show the `SelectedItem` of first combobox (i.e., `selectedAnimalType`) on the `DataGrid`. For example, I would like to see columns such as following on my `DataGrid`:

```
| Animal Type |    Name     |   Age   |
---------------------------------------
|     pets    |   myCat 1   |    2    |
|     pets    |   myCat 2   |    4    |
```

`pets` are passed by `selectedAnimalType` to the converter, and converter uses this information plus `selectedAnimalCategory` to get `myCat 1` and `myCat 2`. Therefore, would it be possible to return multiple values from the `MultiValueConverter` so that I see my `DataGrid` as aforementioned ?

Just in case anyone is interested to see a minimal possible running code example, I prepared a small project of my question and you can find the source-code [here on DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9bnu0u2j1z17r1/WpfApplication1.rar?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weirdness of that design aside...

**No, you cannot**
The signature of `Convert` is:

```
Object Convert(
    Object[] values,
    Type targetType,
    Object parameter,
    CultureInfo culture
)
```

([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.convert(v=vs.110).aspx))

So you have to return a single object. That object could even be a `Tuple<string, object>` which would approximate multiple return values, but thats an even *worse* design.

If you want that data in your `DataGrid` I would just name your combo-box and do an `ElementName` binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Animal Type" 
Binding="{Binding ElementName=TypeComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

In a more general case, access the main data context by naming your root element "Root" and doing this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Animal Type" 
Binding="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.SelectedType}"/>
```

Comment: That's possible in the very simplified scenario. But actually I would like to bind to the ViewModel property `SelectedAnimalType` which can be updated from different sources (and the ComboBox is just one of them).

Comment: @Hamed No problem, see my edit (this is how you bind commands in a data grid by the way)

Comment: I'm confused with "root element", is it the "MainWindow" in the source-code I uploaded ?

Comment: @Hamed Sorry for the delay. I usually apply that to the "Window", "Page", or "UserControl" element.